# associative array total value count

Tags: php

Check array print_r() view bellow. I want to get total of only "amount" value. And output should not in array. It should be a simple integer value. So result should be 4+3+9= 16

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [portfolio_id] => 1
                [stock_id] => 1
                [amount] => 4
                [date] => 04/02/2017
                [created_at] => 2017-04-02 09:04:30
                [updated_at] => 2017-04-02 09:04:30
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [portfolio_id] => 1
                [stock_id] => 3
                [amount] => 3
                [date] => 04/02/2017
                [created_at] => 2017-04-02 09:03:40
                [updated_at] => 2017-04-02 09:03:40
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [portfolio_id] => 1
                [stock_id] => 4
                [amount] => 9
                [date] => 04/02/2017
                [created_at] => 2017-04-02 09:03:36
                [updated_at] => 2017-04-02 09:03:36
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `array_sum(array_column($input, 'amount'));`

`array_column` will return the values of `amount` key & `array_sum` calculate the sum of values in the returned array

Comment: Always consider to add live demo link : https://eval.in/766287 it's make other clear about your code working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
function sum($carry, $item)// summing on amount column of the inner array $item
{
    $carry += $item["amount"];
    return $carry;
}
echo "Amount sum : ".array_reduce($a, "sum");// output : 59
```

Example :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: lenovo
 * Date: 4/2/2017
 * Time: 11:17 AM
 */

  $array = array
     (
        array("name"=>"Volvo","amount"=>22,"id"=>18),
        array("name"=>"BMW","amount"=>15,"id"=>13),
        array("name"=>"Saab","amount"=>5,"id"=>2),
        array("name"=>"Land Rover","amount"=>17,"id"=>15)
     );

    function sum($carry, $item)
    {
        $carry += $item["amount"];
        return $carry;
    }
    echo "Amount sum : " .array_reduce($array, "sum");// output : 59
```

Good  luck.